# Touchpad not detected on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, touchpad, hardware, lts

I'm using a Chuwi Gemibook Pro and installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The touchpad doesn't work (it did, in Linux Mint) but the usb mouse does. The kernel version, currently, is "5.19.0-46-generic".

I added `"i8042.reset"` to the `"quiet splash"` command, but that did not help. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.